# Total combinations from number of unique combination?

Tags: permutations, combinations

How can you find count of the total combinations possible if you have the count of unique combinations?

Suppose I need to form a sum of $3$ using $\{1,2\}$
Unique combn. $(1+1+1)$,
$(1+2)$
hence '$2$' unique
but total is '$3$' i.e,
$(1+1+1)$,
$(1+2)$,
$(2+1)$

I know the elements used to make the combination

Note: Number of unique combinations (ie. 2 here) is known.

How can I find the total number of combination given the unique combinations?

Comment: You expect there to be some simple function which converts a [restricted partition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) into a restricted [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) without knowing more details?  Surely, there could be some values of $n,k$ such that the number of restricted partitions are the same but the number of restricted compositions are different.

Comment: I need to form a given sum (here 3), using numbers {1,2} and tell the total combinations of {1,2} possible, I am able to find the total unique sets that give the sum (here 3), but not the total. Is it possible to do so using the unique count?

Comment: Using the count alone?  No.  Using the desired sum and list of available numbers?  Yes, but you could do that anyways without ever looking at the restricted partition number (*number of "unique combinations" using your words*) in the first place.

Comment: Please tell me how, I know the desired sum and numbers available. That is my exact problem, I think I over complicated it!

Comment: Lets say my desired sum is 3 and numbers available is {1,2}. How do I find total combinations of 1 and 2 to form sum 3 ?

Comment: Recurrence relations is a good way to go for most of these restricted compositions problems (*please use correct terminology, these are not combinations, they are compositions*).  It is a very common problem to find the total number of restricted compositions whose sum is $n$ using only values of $1$ and $2$... You will find the answers wind up being the fibonacci sequence.  The technique is easily adapted to other sets of available numbers to use in the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the number of *restricted compositions* (*use the correct terminology*) with a desired sum $n$ and available numbers $\{1,2\}$, what I will label $f(n)$, recognize the following:

$f(1)=1$ (*as the only possibility is the sum with only one term: $(1)$*)

$f(2)=2$ (*as there are two possibilities: $(1+1)$ and $(2)$*)

> alternatively, and preferably, recognize that $f(0)=1$ as there *is* in fact a sum whose sum is zero using terms $1$ and $2$... the "*empty sum*"... $(~)$.  This is somewhat abstract, but I strongly encourage coming to grips with this as using counts related to objects of size zero can *greatly* simplify arithmetic in many instances

Next, recognize that for each $n\geq 3$ you have $f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)$ which is seen by noting that every such restricted composition either begins with a "$1+\dots$" with a sum of $n-1$ following which can be arranged in $f(n-1)$ ways, or it will begin with $2+\dots$ with a sum of $n-2$ following which can be arranged in $f(n-2)$ ways.

Now... you should recognize this... $f(1)=1, f(2)=2, f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$... this is precisely the fibonacci sequence.  So... here we found that $f(n)$ is precisely equal to $F_n$.

No knowledge of the related problem counting restricted *partitions* rather than restricted compositions was needed.

The technique can obviously be adapted... the number of restricted compositions with sum $n$ using terms $\{1,2,3\}$ for instance would be the tribonacci numbers satisfying the recurrence $t(1)=1, t(2)=2, t(3)=4, t(n)=t(n-1)+t(n-2)+t(n-3)$ or the number of restricted compositions with sum $n$ using terms $\{2,5\}$ for instance would be $a(1)=a(3)=0, a(2)=a(4)=a(5)=1$ and $a(n)=a(n-2)+a(n-5)$ for each $n\geq 6$ and so on...

> Coming to terms with the zero object can simplify a lot of the above for finding initial conditions.  We could instead have had $a(n)=0$ for all $n<0$ and $a(0)=1$, reducing the need to actually manually find initial conditions

Coming up with a closed form for these types of linear recurrences is already covered in great detail in related chapters in books, and otherwise for now the current presentation of the answer in terms of a recurrence relation is generally considered sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

The two objects you are interested in here are commonly called "[compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics))" and "[partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))" of integers, where we count two compositions as different if the order of the parts is different (i.e. $(1+2)$ is a different composition than $(2+1)$).

So when you say you want to count the unique combinations, that is the same as counting partitions of n.

The partition function is a very important function in number theory and is usualy denoted by $p(n)$ for the number of partitions of the natural number $n$.

There is no known exact closed-form expression for the partition function, but a way to compute it is via the recurrence
$$p(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k (p(n - \frac{k(3k-1)}{2}) + p(n - \frac{k(3k+1)}{2}))$$

known as the Euler pentagonal theorem.
There is plenty more to say about paritions of integers.

Comment: These are restricted partitions, not simply partitions.  Note that the OP only uses digits $1$ and $2$, but does not use digit $3$, giving the possibilities $(1+1+1), (1+2)$ but not $(3)$

Comment: Further, this does nothing to address the actual question being asked of how to use the value of the one in order to calculate the other.

Comment: Oh I see you're right. Then I think we need to clarify what exactly is the restriction the OP is working with. Are we restricting the size of parts we're using or are we given a set of parts we're allowed to use?